# Does Autodesk forge only support 3D model presentations? Can I display a two-dimensional floor plan?

Tags: autodesk-forge

At present, the 3D model is displayed according to the documentation provided by the Autodesk forge official website, but the relevant api or extension is not provided to directly display the 2D floor plan. Please tell me the specific steps, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For Revit 2D view translation, please check you have picked them in any view sets of the [Publish Settings](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Revit-CAR/files/GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3-htm.html).

In the viewer side, please try to specify a proper view filter `role: 2d` in your code while loading models. For example,

```
const filter = {
    type:'geometry',
    role: '2d' //!<<< the key
};

const rootItem = doc.getRoot();
const viewables = rootItem.search(filter);

viewer.loadDocumentNode( doc, viewables[0] );
```

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/#step-2-load-model-in-manifest

Comment: Thanks for this! Used your example to load 3D views by default by changing "role" to "3d".